# How to format Gunicorn error logs using config file?

Tags: python, logging, devops, gunicorn

I can format the access-log of [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) using the config below. But checking [Gunicorn documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#access-log-format), it seems there isn't any obvious flag/attribute to set the format of the error log (e.g. error_log_format). Does Gunicorn support error formatting, if so, how can set it up?

gunicorn.config.py

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:6001"
workers = 7
errorlog = 'logs/gunicorn-errors.txt'
loglevel = 'error'
accesslog='-'
access_log_format = '%(t)s %(s)s - %(m)s %(U)s'
```

Results in log format like:

> [12/May/2020:14:53:15 -0700] 200 - GET /api

I've seen this 2-year old [stack-overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088749/how-can-i-configure-gunicorn-to-use-a-consistent-error-log-format) where someone seemed to have a suggestion, but it's unclear what gunicorn version they had or how to translate their config into a python config.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @kennysong Unfortunately not. I've just been using the default format. 